What is the difference between the Right Angles Congruence Theorem and Euclid's Fourth Postulate?
In Euclid's "Elements", the fourth postulate states that "All right angles are congruent." However, in some textbooks, they claim this is a theorem due to its nature of being able to be proved.
This is how they proved the theorem:
"Let $\angle A$ and $\angle B$ be right angles. Then, by definition, $m\angle A=90^\circ$ and $m\angle B=90^\circ$. By the Substitution Property of Equality, $m\angle A=m\angle B$. Therefore, by the definition of congruences, we proved $\angle A\cong\angle B$."
Is this proof using circular reasoning (in that the definition is based on the postulate itself, that saying right angles have a measure of 90 degrees already uses the postulate itself), or is Euclid wrong in the first place?
Thanks for any answers in advance.

Euclid does not use degree measure in his definition of the right angle. In fact, his postulate is based on the definition so I do not think a theorem would be appropriate here. To use a theorem, one would need a postulate that equal (congruent angles have equal measure).

You can use Euclid/Hilbert like axioms to define angle measures, then two angles are congruent is equivalent to them having the same measures. This is, for example, done in Greenberg's geometry book. The answer to your question depends on the choice of axiom system.
